Discrepancy in Matplotlib Histograms of the Same Data Across Subplots
I am trying to create a histogram of my dataset. The data is sparse, so plotting it all in one graph makes it appear nearly empty. To address this, I decided to create four separate subplots, each focusing on a different domain of the data to make the graphs more meaningful.
However, I noticed an issue: when I plot the same domain on two separate subplots, the charts look slightly different. Since both subplots are based on the exact same underlying data and parameters, I expected the charts to look identical.
I cannot share the original dataset, but I created simulated data that reproduces the same issue. Any insights into why this discrepancy occurs and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.
The four different subplots can be created with the following code:
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist = st.chi.rvs(0.233966,
                  loc=-5.29021*10**-23,
                  scale=3.955368*10**4,
                  size=110000)
 
bins = np.concatenate((np.linspace(0, 10000, 1000,),
                       np.linspace(10100,100000, 1000),
                       np.linspace(101000, 1000000, 1000),
                       np.linspace(1010000, 4000000, 40)))
 
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(12,8))
 
y, x, l = axs[0,0].hist(dist, bins=bins, density=True)
start_plot = 0
end_plot = 5000
y_max = np.max(y[(x[:-1]<end_plot) & (x[:-1]>start_plot)])
axs[0, 0].set_xlim((start_plot, end_plot))
axs[0,0].set_ylim((0, y_max))
 
axs[0,1].hist(dist, bins=bins, density=True)
start_plot = 0
end_plot = 5000
y_max = np.max(y[(x[:-1]<end_plot) & (x[:-1]>start_plot)])
axs[0,1].set_xlim((start_plot, end_plot))
axs[0,1].set_ylim((0, y_max))
 
axs[1,0].hist(dist, bins=bins, density=True)
start_plot = 5000
end_plot = 50000
y_max = np.max(y[(x[:-1]<end_plot) & (x[:-1]>start_plot)])
axs[1,0].set_xlim((start_plot, end_plot))
axs[1,0].set_ylim((0, y_max))
 
axs[1,1].hist(dist, bins=bins, density=True)
start_plot = 50000
end_plot = 1000000
y_max = np.max(y[(x[:-1]<end_plot) & (x[:-1]>start_plot)])
axs[1,1].set_xlim((start_plot, end_plot))
axs[1,1].set_ylim((0, y_max))
 
plt.show()

The top two subplots should show the same data, however they are very clearly different:

Furthermore, if I do not plot the bottom two subplots, the top two subplots change:
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, nrows=2, figsize=(12,8))
 
y, x, l = axs[0,0].hist(dist, bins=bins, density=True)
start_plot = 0
end_plot = 5000
y_max = np.max(y[(x[:-1]<end_plot) & (x[:-1]>start_plot)])
axs[0, 0].set_xlim((start_plot, end_plot))
axs[0,0].set_ylim((0, y_max))
 
axs[0,1].hist(dist, bins=bins, density=True)
start_plot = 0
end_plot = 5000
y_max = np.max(y[(x[:-1]<end_plot) & (x[:-1]>start_plot)])
axs[0,1].set_xlim((start_plot, end_plot))
axs[0,1].set_ylim((0, y_max))


They appear more similar now, but looking closely, one can see they are not the same. I looked at the patches, and the patches look identical in terms of the x-positions, width, and height. So, not sure what's going on. Any ideas?

See Changing histograms in pyplot's subplots and the questions that are linked there.  Basically, the widths of the bars are less than a pixel. Due to different rounding, they are shown slightly different. Adding an edgecolor helps a bit: hist(..., lw=0.5, edgecolor='steelblue').  (Areas are drawn without antialiasing, while lines do get antialiasing)

You can also try adding histtype='stepfilled' to your hist call.  This will draw the histogram as one large path instead of the individual bars, and is less affected by the sampling issue.
